# Social Plugins Issues on Website

Tags: twitter

We recently tried to put Social Plugins on our website. The plugins are working really nice.

The only problem we guys are facing is that, when we are clicking on number of Tweets links for twitter plugin, its taking us to twitter page and showing no tweets !

How this problem can be solved ?

Comment: would it be possible to have the link to your website?